# Most efficient way to fill a text template with object properties and other values

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have programmers that work with different objects like Products which have Manufacturers and Locations.

I have webdesigners that need to define configuration rules which are in fact templates which should be able to use variable elements that come from the Products or Manufacturers.

So from a config file we read a string like:

```
string template = "Hello visitor, look at this [Product.Name] made by [Product.Manufacturer.Name], today it costs only [Price]";
```

Now i'm looking for the most generic setup, with the best performance, for the programmers to have something like this:

```
public static ParseTemplate(string template, params string[] values){
    //parsing
}
```

or even better (idea sketching modus)

```
public static ParseTemplate(string template, params object[] objects){
    //parsing
    return template.Replace("[objectName.PropertyName]", objectName.PropertyValue);

}
```

The programmers should be able point at a template, throw whatever values/objects they have at this template, and a parsed string with all possible placeholders replaced with the correct values should be returned;

Should we first build up a list with KeyValuePairs? That is what i have done for now, but then the programmers would have to fill these lists with pairs explicitly, so i'm looking for something more simple on that side.

Would it be possible for them to just throw in the 'raw object', and to have a helper that sorts out the properties of these objects and get their values?

Is reflection something that could help us out? Or is there perhaps an easier way?

Comment: I think this would be specific to your choice of UI framework, i.e. WPF, ASP.NET.

Comment: You can also use client side templating frameworks like HandlebarJS which already doing all that...

Comment: Ah, okay, forgot to add that. We are working in ASP.NET

Comment: What did you try? Maybe you're interested in outsourcing?

Comment: I have updated my question with what i have tried.